# cannot insert images to word document created through C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I'm trying to create a word document, insert some pictures and save it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
namespace Snapper
{
    class WordDocumentGenerator
    {
        public void CreateWordDocument(string fileName)
        {
            string originalPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string path = originalPath;
            path += @"\snapshots";
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(path);

            Word._Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
            Word._Document wordDoc;
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                            ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

            wordDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"\snap1.jpg");
            wordDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"\snap2.jpg");

            path = originalPath;
            path += @"\documents";
            DirectoryInfo docDir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            if (!docDir.Exists)
            {
                docDir.Create();
            }
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(path);
            Object savePath = path + @"\" + fileName + ".doc";

            wordDoc.SaveAs(ref savePath,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing
               );
            wordDoc.Close(SaveChanges: true);
        }

    }
}
```

I'm getting an unhandled exception error box saying that this is not a valid filename for addpicture() method. What am I doing wrong?

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A1420): This is not a valid file name.
Try one or more of the following:
* Check the path to make sure it was typed correctly.
* Select a file from the list of files and folders.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShapes.AddPicture(String FileName, Object& LinkToFile, Object& SaveWithDocument, Object& Range)
   at Snapper.WordDocumentGenerator.CreateWordDocument(String fileName) in D:\RESOURCES\Projects\Visual Studio Projects\Snapper\Snapper\GenerateWordDocument.cs:line 27
   at Snapper.SnapperForm.CreateDocumentButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\RESOURCES\Projects\Visual Studio Projects\Snapper\Snapper\SnapperForm.cs:line 130
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4971 (win7RTMGDR.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Snapper
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///D:/RESOURCES/Projects/Visual%20Studio%20Projects/Snapper/Snapper/bin/Debug/Snapper.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4977 (win7RTMGDR.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4971 (win7RTMGDR.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4980 (win7RTMGDR.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
HotKeys
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///D:/RESOURCES/Projects/Visual%20Studio%20Projects/Snapper/Snapper/bin/Debug/HotKeys.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
    Assembly Version: 14.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 14.0.4762.1000
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word/14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: What kind of exception do you get?

Comment: Hab you tried to us th fully qualified path, instead o doing the get/set current directory dance?

Comment: Is "\snap1.jpg" a valid filename? Did you try "snap1.jpg"?

Comment: @PhoenixReborn, I've tried snap1.jpg and still the error is same

Comment: @kunaguvarun Check your paths then. Obviously your program cannot find a file named "snap1.jpg" in the current path. Try supplying the full path to the `AddPicture` method.

Comment: @PhoenixReborn, The path is correct. What I've done is concatenate path as well as filename in the AddPicture method. Now evertthing is fine. Thank you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why dont you test the following, just to test if it works!

```
string originalPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string  path = @"\snapshots";
string dirpath = Path.Combine(originalPath, path);
string filepath = @"snap1.jpg"
string completepath = Path.Combine(dirpath, filepath);
```

**Note the filename...!** No starting "\"  
Kinda hard when you dont hand out the exact exception.

Comment: Nope. Still the same exception

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all. I've concatenated path along with filename in the AddPicture() method. Now everyhting is working as expected.

Comment: You should then accept @Rusty Mcpherson's answer that was suggesting this.